# Copying small portions of a file from unix/linux server with only read permission

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

There is a large file sitting on a server in which I only have read permission (not write). I am only interested in the first couple of megabytes in the head of the file and would like to avoid copying the entire large file to my computer. Is it possible to do so?

(note that I cannot use dd or split on the server since this requires write access)

Comment: `dd` doesn't require write access.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible via `ssh` and `head`:

```
$ ssh user@server "head -c NUM_BYTES /path/to/file" > file.bin
```

That will ssh into the server and run the head command on /path/to/file, read off the first NUM_BYTES, and put it locally into a file called file.bin.

Comment: Use `dd` when working with binary files. `ssh user@server "dd if=file count=10" >file.bin`

Comment: `head` works fine too.  Do you know a reason why it's not?

Comment: Because `head` is designed for manipulating text files and therefore will open the file in text mode.

Comment: I'd have to inspect source code to be sure, but `dd` is quite possibly more efficient than `head` because you can specify block size. A good implementation of `head` would buffer blocks as well, but it's entirely possible that `head` could just read a byte at a time, which is much less efficient. @Let_Me_Be Linux/Unix don't distinguish between "text mode" and "binary mode", unlike certain other operating systems.

Comment: @twalberg `head` can't properly read binary files anyway so the fact that it would be slower is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I suspect that, on Linux/Unix, you might have a hard time proving that assertion.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be no it doesn't, it uses [binary mode](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/head.c#n852).

Comment: @jszakmeister Yeah you are right, I just checked as well. Well, that's what I get for not verifying information I get from other people :-/

Comment: @Let_Me_Be @jszakmeister Ok, but on my Linux box, `O_BINARY` is defined as `0`... Makes it a bit of a no-op...

Comment: @twalberg Yes, in Linux environments, there is no text mode.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I know how you feel!

Comment: @twalberg That's cause `'\n'` is one character on Linux. This doesn't hold for other Unixes.

Comment: Huh? All Unices I know represent line feed as one character, in one byte. Perhaps you're mixing up with DOS?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I have found that it is possible with dd for example,

dd if=inputfile.txt of=dest/outputfile.txt count=1 bs=1M